# What's the correct way to redirect the user when a Batch API job finishes?

Tags: 7, batch-operations

I've got a form that starts a batch job. What's the right way to redirect them after it finishes? Calling drupal_goto() in my finish function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
drupal_goto('your/hookmenu/link', array('query' => array('destination', $_GET['destination'])));
```

Comment: Yeah, I know how `drupal_goto()` works I'm just curious if there's a better way, something like `$form_state['redirect']`

Comment: I don't know a better one, but an alternative is `header('Location: index.php?q=node");` But I will not use it personally. `$form_redirect['redirect']` will not work outside a form context. So drupal_goto is the only robust way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

You can set 'redirect' in [hook_batch_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_batch_alter/7).
For example:

```
$batch['form_state']['redirect']['path'] = 'cart';
```

Comment: Do you have a sample for how that would work? It doesn't seem like the batch is a form.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the redirect path in the moment you start the batch, you can

```
batch_process('my/destination/path');
```

See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/batch_process/7

Comment: What if we have query string as well in the path. For example my/destination/path?destination=admin/content

Comment: For complex cases, it's better to use custom redirect callback.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to do that?

Comment: Yes. 1) Read docs: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/batch_process/7 2) Pay attention to `$redirect_callback` ;)

Answer (score 0):

i'm create link to form (created by form api) that runs the batch with get-parameter "?destination=myRedirectPath".

batch lanch on function form_submit() and take info about redirect after batch from url.

without "goto".